# Hollow Progress Bars in Ubuntu 13.04 Software Center

Tags: software-center

I've noticed in Ubuntu 13.04 (and 12.10) that the progress bars in the Software Center have a transparent space in the middle, not solid orange, which shows the color of the background behind it. It's nit-picky but I was wondering if there is a way to fix this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is still appearing in 13.10

Comment: I can confirm that this is happing in 13.10

Comment: If you believe it's a bug, just report it: [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121)

Answer (score -1):

I don't suppose anything is broken here. Maybe ubuntu just moved away from the completely orange-filled progress bar to this swanky version for software center.